# Can't start Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have installed Hive and run the command

```
schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
```

for initializing the database. But showing the following error.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubundu/Downloads/Hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubundu/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

2022-04-14 13:56:15,607 INFO  conf.HiveConf (HiveConf.java:findConfigFile(187)) - Found configuration file file:/home/ubundu/hive/conf/hive-site.xml

2022-04-14 13:56:16,063 ERROR shims.ShimLoader (ShimLoader.java:getHadoopShims(88)) - Error loading shims

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${declared"

    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)

    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:141)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:112)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:86)

    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:1485)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${declared"

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:89)

    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:1485)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${declared"

    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)

    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getMajorVersion(ShimLoader.java:141)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:112)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:86)

    ... 7 more
```

Comment: it would help if you indicated which version of hive you were using.

Answer (score 0):

The error is internal to the `schemaTool` command.

I'd recommend using a different version of Hive to start, and using a database other than the default Derby database such as MySQL/MariaDB or Postgres.